# What could explain an extremely high TTFB (~20-30s) when not logged in, but then drastically reduced when logged in?

Tags: performance

Tested this across browsers, essentially my site has a TTFB of about \~25s when visiting a page on the site. However, if logged in as a user, TTFB going to any page on the front-end is drastically reduced (<1s). Once logged out, TTFB goes back up to \~25s.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to troubleshoot disabling plugins since it is a live site for my company, and I can't recreate the issue when copying the site locally or to a different site on the server.

As for plugins, other than the custom ones we have set up (which may very well be the issue), we're using Gravity Forms, The Event Calendar, and Safe Redirect Manager. There's no caching plugin set up.

I set up a mu-plugin that fires under the `option_active_plugins` filter and disables ALL plugins on a page I define. Still  crazy high TTFB, so I guess that rules out if the issue is a plugin (unless plugin scripts are still run prior to that filter, I am not sure)

Comment: Maybe you have a redirection issue. You mentioned you are using a redirect manager plugin, it can cause some trouble. You can also check the console log of your browser ( Network tab ), and check if you are facing a redirect chain.

Comment: Disabled Safe Redirect Manager, no change far as I could see.

Comment: Did you have a look to the network tab (dev console)? You will see if admin-ajax.php has been blocked for simple user.

Comment: I don't see admin-ajax.php in the network tab either logged in or not logged in. I can see that admin-ajax.php is allowed in robots.txt

Comment: Are you using a network site? If yes, please note (if you haven't noticed yet) network activated plugins will not get deactivated with 'option_active_plugins'.